# Programmatically adding in & connecting to non-broadcasting Wifi networks on Android

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi

I'm playing around with adding in Wifi networks on Android and I'm wondering how you're supposed to connect to a wifi network that isn't broadcasting its SSID (whether it has an empty SSID or a a clear SSID with \0s).

This is what I'm currently using for Wifi networks that broadcast their SSIDs:

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = quote(input);
conf.preSharedKey = quote("somepassword");

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(wifiManager.addNetwork(conf), true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
  string networkSSID = "";
  string networkPass = "somepassword";

  WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
  wifiConfig.Ssid = string.Format("\"{0}\"", networkSSID);
  wifiConfig.PreSharedKey = string.Format("\"{0}\"", networkPass);

  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

  // Use ID
  int netId = wifiManager.AddNetwork(wifiConfig);
  wifiManager.Disconnect();
  wifiManager.EnableNetwork(netId, true);
  wifiManager.Reconnect();
```